# Formula to extract 6 digit number from a cell in 2016 excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2016

I’m looking for an excel 2016 formula to help extract exactly 6 digits from a cell. The good news is that if there is a 6 digit number, it will be standalone (ie, does not start or end with letters or other characters). The bad news is that the cell does not always have the same number of characters in it, the cells will often have other text and numbers within it, some cells won’t have any standalone six digit numbers at all, the six digit number will not always be the in the exact same spot of the cell (it won’t always be the first characters or the last characters of the cell). Look at a few examples below of what I’m looking for:

| Original Cell | What I Want Extracted | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 295900 PADOXGH | 295900 | Only pulled the 6 digit number |
| 295901 AHIPOSY LTECH | 295901 | Only pulled the 6 digit number |
| 296018 Certified Receiviables Quiz PLOQUIZ | 296018 | Only pulled the 6 digit number |
| V06644 V09523 DELI010 601848123 DeliveryReceivables DELIVERY INC 296016 LOGISTICS | 296016 | Extracted the only 6 digit number. Notice that it ignored the 9 digit number (it didn't try to take that 9 digit number and break it into 6). It also ignored the 5 digit number that started with a V. |
| AKORPE V12347 MEL712 | Nothing found | No standalone 6 digit number, so it finds nothing |
| V123568 | Nothing found | No standalone 6 digit number, so it finds nothing |
| 978123074 V098872 12350c | Nothing found | No standalone 6 digit number, so it finds nothing |

I haven't found a formula thus far that meets the needs I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FILTERXML()` function:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b[string-length()=6 and number()=.]"),"Nothing Found")
```

---

To know more about `FILTERXML()` and its usages, you can read here posted by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir

**[Excel - Extract substring(s) from string using FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml)**

---

Another alternative method:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,7,--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",REPT(" ",100)),COLUMN($A$1:$Z$1)*100-99,100)/
 (LEN(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",REPT(" ",100)),COLUMN($A$1:$Z$1)*100-99,100))=6),1),"Nothing Found")
```

---

Comment: Nope, that does not work. On some with cells it finds nothing when there is clearly a 6 digit number.

Comment: That sounds vague, when you have not shown what you have tried on your own, and no given sample data where it wont work.

Comment: Post example where it is not working on your end @footballgames101

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Excel 2016:

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFERROR(MID(" "&TRIM(A2)&" ",ROW($1:$99),8)/(LEN(--MID(" "&TRIM(A2)&" ",ROW($1:$99),8))=6),""))`

This needs being entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`